# Format dom as expression using css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm creating a site that uses tags and needs to perform basic tag algebra with operators `not`, `and`, `or`.  I have a dom element that describes the expression but can't display the expression using css.

Consider the following expression:

```
([Green] or ((not [Blue]) and ([Red] or (not [Yellow]))))
```

Which is represented in the dom as:

```
<span class="tag-expression">
  <span class="tag-or">
    <span class="tag" value="green">Green</span>
    <span class="tag-and">
      <span class="tag-not">
        <span class="tag" value="blue">Blue</span>    
      </span>
      <span class="tag-or">
        <span class="tag" value="red">Red</span>
        <span class="tag-not">
          <span class="tag" value="yellow">Yellow</span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

I've managed to include the parenthesis using css' `:before` and `:after` tied with the `content` attribute ([jfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zPZhg/)).  But have no luck showing the operators `¬`, `&`, `|`.  I've been toying with including a `<span class="operator"/>` with an image background but I was wondering is there is another way to make this using the `:before` and `:after` selectors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Keep in mind `:before` and `:after` are not nestable within the same element - that'll make this a little more difficult to pull off.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, it works with what you provided me in the example, you should test it out in more complex expressions to make sure it is correct.

I added some complex CSS selectors at the end of your CSS script for showing your operators:

```
.tag-expression .tag-or > span:nth-child(2):before {
    content: ' | (';   
}

.tag-expression .tag-and > span:first-child:after {
    content: ' ) & ';
}

.tag-expression .tag-not:before {
    content: ' ( ¬ ';
}​
```

You can checkout this in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPZhg/2/).  Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Your first rule is overriding your last rule due to specificity issues, so it shows up as `| (` and not `( ¬`.